# How to replace missing values with median value?

Tags: r

I have data from https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBA0P.png and it have missing values for column "Age".  I want to replace `NA` values with median of "Age".

I tried this, but its not working:

```
library(tidyverse)
T_Title %>% 
  group_by(Pclass, Title) %>%
  mutate(Age = ifelse(is.na(Age), median(Age, na.rm = T, Age)))
```

On running these code, I am getting the error:

> Error in ifelse(is.na(Age), median(Age, na.rm = T, Age)) : 
>         argument "no" is missing, with no default

How to fix this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One of your brackets is closing at the wrong place. Your last line should probably be `mutate(Age = ifelse(is.na(Age), median(Age, na.rm = T), Age))`

Comment: Its works!! Thank you!